# selenium code for accessing button type submit

Tags: selenium

i want to access the submit button having code

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
```

I have tried for ;

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Save")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Save")).submit();
```

but raising an error of : `No such element Unable to locate Element`

Comment: The `By.name()` requires a class-name to be passed to it for Webdriver to find the element. "Save" is not the class-name of that element. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary"));` would work, as long as the button's class is unique. If not, you'll likely need to use `By.xpath("//input[@value, 'Save']")`

Comment: There is no `name="save"` attribute in your `<input>`, just add it

Comment: Thank you it worked by cssSelector

Comment: and more doubt while doing normal testing on the firefox browser the perticular functionality works but after running through selenium scripting it didn't works why

Answer (score 0):

Your element has no name, it has a tag and some class names which may or may not be unique across the page you are testing. These may work but we might need to see more of the page.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn.btn-primary")).click();
```

You may find the page http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp useful as it gives you an introduction to the different ways to find elements on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Add a sleep time or wait before the submit.

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.name("Save")).click();
```

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: still raising an error No such element Unable to locate Element the html code is <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">